# How assing new column value for only specific one

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a bit complex query to do in BigQuery.

Please find below example.

I have :

| Team | Team type |
| --- | --- |
| Team 1 | B1 |
| Team 1 | B2 |
| Team 2 | B3 |
| Team 2 | B4 |
| Team 3 | B5 |
| Team 3 | B6 |

I need to have

| Team | Teamtype | Team_model |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Team 1 | B1 | Team x |
| Team 1 | B2 | Team 1 |
| Team 2 | B3 | Team 2 |
| Team 2 | B4 | Team 2 |
| Team 3 | B5 | Team 3 |
| Team 3 | B6 | Team 3 |

In similar logic like this

CASE
WHEN teamtype = A1 THEN "Team x"
ELSE team_model = %team%
END
AS team_model

I know that in biq query you cant do this way. Would anyone know please how to perform this type of action?

Thank you!

Regards,
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track.  You may use this version:

```sql
SELECT Team, Teamtype, CASE Teamtype WHEN 'B1' THEN 'Team x' ELSE Team END AS Team_model
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY Team, Teamtype;
```

Comment: Oh yes! Sometimes the simple solution is not the even most visible...THANKS!